# Layout 2 TextViews with different "priorities"

Tags: android, textview, alignment, android-linearlayout

I have this

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:ellipsize="end" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:maxLines="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But i want text2 to have "higher priority" than text1

**Meaning In the case where the screen doesn't fit both i need to have this behavior:**

Text2 must always be fully displayed in a single line unless it's over 80% of the screen, in that case use "..."

Text1 uses whatever space is left from Text2, can use multiple lines, if it doesn't fit, it should use the "..." at the end

Is this possible with LinearLayout or maybe i should use a different container instead?

Comment: i don't know whether it is possible with any layout that android provides. you may have to write custom view or manage this programatically...

Comment: Have you tried using `layout_weight`?

Comment: @xFighter i prefer only with xml

Comment: @yogur I doubt it's possible with weight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `ConstraintLayout`

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: This looks promising

Answer (score -2):

Your best bet would be to use Fragments, refer to this tutorial:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#Create

They allow for exactly what you are looking for.